# How can I connect seven schools worldwide to create and share QGIS projects?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, qgis-server

I am looking at a possible programme to connect seven schools ( all English capable ) located around the world to set up and share QGIS data and projects about their own local area among the group.

What type of open source software ( OSGEO ???) is available to do this and where can I find documentation on how it all goes together?  Is there a cloud server system that I can use?

Has this been done before using QGIS?

Comment: Where have you searched prior to posting here?  If you can narrow the focus of your question down to a specific concern that you have with something that you have tried or are about to try then I suspect that your question can be re-opened.

Comment: QGIS server will do the trick as far I know.